# Input format for functions in package strucchange?

Tags: r, regression, trend

I'm trying to do change point detection with ´monitor´ from the strucchange package, but I have trouble getting a useful output.

My input is a time stamped dataframe, and I would like the breaks to be returned as dates, but they are returned as observation number:

```
cDF1 <- myDF[1:80,]

> cDF1[1:3,]
        Year Month Value
2000-10 2000   Oct     1
2001-01 2001   Jan     1
2001-04 2001   Apr     1

me.mefp <- mefp(Value~1, type="ME", rescale=TRUE,
+                       data=cDF1, alpha=0.05)

cDF1 <- myDF[1:104,]

> me.mefp <- monitor(me.mefp)
Break detected at observation # 98
```

In the strucchange manual, there are examples in which the time stamps are kept, but I can't figure out what they difference in format is.

It makes no difference if I make the data frame into a time series.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mefp`/`monitor` functions can only deal with `ts` time series. Hence, you can either supply a `data` argument that is a (multivariate) `ts`, a `data.frame` where the response variable is a `ts` or a standalone `ts` without a `data` argument. In your case, the data appears to be quarterly and as there are no regressors (except a constant) a standalone time series is probably most convenient.

As an artificial example, I simulate 100 observations from a quarterly time series:

```
set.seed(1)
Value <- ts(rnorm(100, mean = rep(0:1, c(70, 30)), sd = 0.5),
  start = c(1990, 1), freq = 4)
plot(Value)
```

[image: time series]

Then I select the data up to the end of 1999 as the history period and initialize the monitoring process:

```
val <- window(Value, end = c(1999, 4))
m <- mefp(val ~ 1, type = "ME", rescale = TRUE, alpha = 0.05)
```

Then the data can arrive, say until the end of 2009:

```
val <- window(Value, end = c(2009, 4))
m <- monitor(m)
```

And then finally until the end of 2014:

```
val <- window(Value, end = c(2014, 4))
m <- monitor(m)
## Break detected at observation # 81 
plot(m)
```

Here, a break is finally detected and also brought out graphically.

[image: monitoring process]

P.S.: In your example, it appears as if the data were positive counts. If so, taking logs may (or may not) be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your very elaborate answer. Another question though - once a breakpoint has been detected, if I continue monitoring with the same monitor, it just returns `TRUE`and plot a circle at (1,1) if I try plotting it. Is it only possible to detect one breakpoint with `monitor`? Sorry if this should have been posted as a completely separate question.

Comment: Once a breakpoint has been found, you need to re-initialize the monitoring process with a new break-free history period. To select this new history period, often a full `breakpoints()` estimation is used. Alternatively, one can use a reverse-ordered CUSUM test (based on recursive residuals) to see when the back-predictions break down.